# Maximum size of entity in datastore?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

What is the maximum size of an entity in datastore? In mongo a document can be max 16mb, I assume something similar with DS. Anyone know?

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/limits) says 1MB:

> Maximum size for an entity: 1,048,572 bytes (1 MiB - 4 bytes)

Also, take a look at this [blog](http://atastypixel.com/blog/breaking-the-limits-storing-data-bigger-than-1-mb-in-google-app-engines-datastore):

> ... the datastore limits entities to 1 Mb.